# some project about typed racket

Tags: racket, project, typed-racket

I am doing some study in typed racket.To understand typed racket well, I need some typed racket projects . Can anyone please give me some links where I can find some typed racket source code.Thanks

Comment: This question is honestly too broad for SO. You may get good feedback though if you email the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/racket-users

Answer (score 0):

Leif is probably right about this not being right for SO.  But as a quick answer, there is a lot of typed racket code shipped with Racket itself.  On Ubuntu, for example, you can search for the line `#lang typed/racket` in `/usr/share/racket/pkgs`.  Or you can find them on GitHub.  The `math` or `images` libraries might be a good place to start.